# Not sure what exactly what the 'beauty' formula is here

Tags: python

Given a string s, you should return its beauty. The beauty of a string s is defined by the maximum beauty of each index in the string.The beauty of an index in a string s is given
by the formula (left[i]^2 * right[i]^2) where:

- left[i] is the number of indices j such that j < i and s[j] < s[i] (according to ascii values).
- right[i] is the number of indices j such that i < j and s[i] < s[j] (according to ascii values)

The function beauty(s) should return the beauty of s.

Examples:

```
beauty("abc") == 1
beauty("aabb") == 0
```

What I have so far:
I am confused about what the left and right indices are referring to specifically and how the examples got their values

```
def beauty(phrase):
   splitphrase = phrase.split()
   asciilist = []
​
   for x in splitphrase:
      asciilist.append(ord(splitphrase[x])^2)
```

Comment: left[i] is the number of characters to the left of the current character that are "less than" the current character. right[i] is the number of characters to the right of the current character that are "greater than" the current character.

Comment: The fact that they used backets in their notation for `left[i]` and `right[i]` certainly is confusing and misleading. It makes it *look* like they're indexing into some other pair of strings.

Comment: To explain abc: index 0 'a' has left = 0, right = 2 => beauty of 0; index 1 'b' has left = 1, right =1 => beauty = 1; index 2 'c' has left = 2, right = 0 => beauty of 0. The max beauty here is 1, from the b at index 1, and so that's the overall beauty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use enumerate in a comprehension to  compute the values of left and right and then zip then together to get the maximum of product of each left/right pair:

```
def beauty(s):
    left  = ( sum(p<c for p in s[:i])**2 for i,c in enumerate(s)   )
    right = ( sum(p>c for p in s[i:])**2 for i,c in enumerate(s,1) )
    return max(l*r for l,r in zip(left,right))

print(beauty("abc"))   # 1
print(beauty("aabb"))  # 0 
print(beauty("zabcd")) # 4
```

*Note that, given the expected result, I'm interpreting `left[i]^2` and `right[i]^2` as the square of the values (as opposed to the binary XOR operation)*